# RDF document metadata

Tags: metadata, turtle-rdf

I have a software that generates an RDF representation of certain dataset. I want to add to the generated data also some metadata describing not specific data contained in the data set but the document itself - i.e., when the document was created, by which software, which version, etc. The [schema.org](https://schema.org/) properties provide the necessary relationships, but I can not figure out the proper place to attach it. Is there some standard way of saying "this is the metadata about the document itself" in RDF? I use [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/) serialization for RDF but generic answer working with any serialization would be preferable.

Comment: Do you ask where to place the RDF in an HTML document, or how to differentiate triples about the dataset from triples about the document?

Comment: @unor I am asking if there is any standard (or customary) way to express the fact that the subject of the triple in the document containing the triple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a standard place to do this.  A RDF graph is just a collection of triples;  it's not identified by an IRI or anything like that.  (However, in SPARQL datasets, you could post some metadata about a *named graph* by using the name of the graph as the subject in a triple. That would just be a convention, though.  It's not "official" in any sense.)

In the RDF serializations of OWL ontologies, there can be an ontology element (i.e., a resource with the type owl:Ontology), and that can be used to associate some metadata with the ontology.  You'd probably want to adopt an approach like that.  That is, you'd establish a convention with something like

```
@prefix ex: <...>

[] a ex:DatasetRepresentation ;
   ex:created "..." ;
   ex:representationOf <...> .

#... rest of generated content ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with Schema.org, but both DCat and Doublin Core provide means to do so.

In Doublin Core there is the [`identifier`](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/terms/identifier/) Data property. An example:

```
PREFIX : <http://my.domain/meta-data#>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

:1 a dcterms:BibliographicResource ;
    dcterms:identifier <http://my.domain/my-document> .
```

A similar record but now using DCat and the [`landingPage`](http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#landingPage) data property:

```
PREFIX : <http://my.domain/meta-data#>
PREFIX dcat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#>

:1 a dcat:Resource ;
    dcat:landingPage <http://my.domain/my-document> .
```